# Counting cells with specific data validation lists

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, data-validation

Here's the description of the problem I am having in excel.

Column A....... Column B.

Questions...... Response (to be selected from a drop down list)

I have 5 worksheets with nearly 500 questions each in the same format.

I want to count all the cells in column B with a specific drop down list (in this case, "Yes,No"). To reiterate, I am not looking for a formula which counts all the cells with either "Yes" or "No". *I am looking to be able to count all cells which have the option of selecting "Yes" or "No"*

Sifted through common forums for such doubts but have found no answer yet. Please help if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with formulas. You will need VBA.

Conceptually:

1. Start the Macro Recorder.
2. On the first sheet select a cell with the data validation you want to explore.
3. Hit F5 > Special > tick Data Validation > tick Same. This will select all cells that have the same data validation rule.
4. stop the macro recorder and edit the recorded code

You will see something like

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeSameValidation).Select
End Sub
```

You can now count the selected cells with `Selection.Count`. Store that in a variable and repeat step 2 to 3 for each sheet. Add the Selection.Count to the variable and at the end you will have the total number of cells that have that same data validation rule.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Seems like my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

For showing cell as dropdown, you can do it using Data Validation item in Data Tab (`shortcut: Alt > D > L`), then select list and put your option (such Yes,No) that you want to display as choice in the cells. (Comma used to separate the options).

And for Summarize the answers, I prefer Countif(range,rule) formula. for example you have 100 question in Column A (Question Range: A1:A100) and the user answers in B column for each one (Answer Range: B1:B100). For counting "Yes" result you can use this in one other cell like B101: `=COUNTIF(B1:B100,"Yes")`

Comment: This is not about counting the "yes" entries. It's about counting which cells have the same data validation rule applied.